# Nullable or Unique field with doctrine:generate:entity in command line?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm learning about Databases with Doctrine in Symfony2 and I'm wondering if its also possible to directly set fields as null or unique by using the command:

> php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="JeflopoStoreBundle:Product" --fields="myfield:text"

Anyone know something on how to do that or if it's possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is unfortunately not possible. I've checked `Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand` class and there I've found how it parse given fields. It's using private method `parseFields` and there is all logic for parsing fields. And unfortunately it parses only `name`, `type` and `length`, so there is no way to specify `nullable` or `unique` field option using `doctrine:generate:entity` command.

The only way is to extend `Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand` class on your own.